# Applications of Quantum Walks

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Can someone explain to me what real world applications could potentially benefit from the study of quantum random walks?

I have researched a fair amount on how quantum walks operate and their properties but I would like to know the end goal of studying them at a deep level? Is it simply for the sake of it in terms of mathematics or physics, or are there actual real-world applications that can benefit from this research?

Comment: Cross posted at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21483/applications-of-quantum-walks

Comment: This question is on hold because it was simultaneously cross-posted to another Stack Exchange site.